# got error:PreparedStatement... while running java program

Tags: java, sql

i got error while running the java program
my code is:

```
for(int k=0;k<ikm;k++)
 {
 if(word[jm].contains(item1))
  {
  final String query1="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c_ngram WHERE Words = item1";
  final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
  ps.setString(1, item1);
  final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
  if(resultSet.next()) {
  final int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

....

error shows in "final PreparedStatement ps" line

please help me

Comment: Please can you provide the exact exception/error you got??? It will help us to go to root cause....

Comment: hello naruto, my error : java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in class file Blog/POS_tag_f11111 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, you probably meant :

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c_ngram WHERE Words = ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` in query string to set parameter

```
final String query1="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c_ngram WHERE Words = ?";
```

To get details about the error you can use try catch.

Comment: i tried ? in query string to set parameter. again i got same error. can u please tell me where i have to insert try and catch in this code

Comment: error : java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in class file Blog/POS_tag_f11111
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)